# Running PHP-server here with Atom on mac

Tags: php, localhost, atom-editor

Since updating my mac to Montery my php-server 0.8.0 in atom no longer works and I'm given this error

Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
PHP Server could not launch
Have you defined the right path to PHP in your settings? Using PHP

Can anybody help me set this back up? Here are my settings.
[v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTgbT.png)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark icon. This will help others find a working solution more easily.

Answer (score 0):

macOS 12 (”Monterey”) is the first version that no longer ships with PHP included. That said, you will need to install PHP yourself. The [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.packages.php) lists several ways to install it, the most common way is to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

1. Enter the following in a terminal window to install Homebrew

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Now you can install the latest PHP version

```sh
brew install php
```

The last couple of PHP 7.x versions are still [maintained](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/php) by the Homebrew team, for even older releases there's a [”tap”](https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php) (third party repository.)